# Removing noise from wave audio file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, signals

I have two wave files, one is normal version, another one is distorted version. In distorted version, I hear a long beep like sound. Here are the frequency domain plots of normal and distorted version sounds. First one is normal, second one is distorted. notice the scales.
[image: Normal Version]

[image: Distorted Version]

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell without using a marker or zooming in, but it seems you have a sinusoid inserted to your signal, which would explain the continuous beep you hear and the delta like function you have in the spectrum. Try to locate the noise frequency using the marker and filtering it using the filter design tool (type "fdatool" in the command line). I would go for a notch filter at the frequency of the noise, and if this doesn't work a high (~1000) order high pass FIR filter.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the signal in frequency domain, you can also remove the noise there (with a simple threshold) and then you take inverse Fourier transform and you get the noise free signal in time domain.